# Performance issue writing to S3 from Spark Structured Streaming application

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-kafka, amazon-emr, spark-structured-streaming

Basically I am running a structured streaming job 24 x 7, writing to S3. But came across this issue that _spark_metadata is taking hours to write a single file, no new data ingestion is active during this time.

Any idea how to solve this issue and enable no-downtime ingestion?

```
19/10/24 00:48:34 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Existing executor 40 has been removed (new total is 1)
19/10/24 00:49:03 INFO CheckpointFileManager: Writing atomically to s3a://.../data/_spark_metadata/88429.compact using temp file s3a://.../data/_spark_metadata/.88429.compact.00eb0d4b-ec83-4f8c-9a67-4155918a5f83.tmp
19/10/24 03:32:53 INFO CheckpointFileManager: Renamed temp file s3a://.../data/_spark_metadata/.88429.compact.00eb0d4b-ec83-4f8c-9a67-4155918a5f83.tmp to s3a://brivo-prod-dataplatform-kafka-streaming/data/_spark_metadata/88429.compact
19/10/24 03:32:53 INFO FileStreamSinkLog: Current compact batch id = 88429 min compaction batch id to delete = 88329
19/10/24 03:32:54 INFO ManifestFileCommitProtocol: Committed batch 88429
```

Comment: Are you using the default or an s3a committer?

Comment: yes, i am writing AVRO instead of parquet. So AWS EMRFS S3-Optimized Committer is not applicable.

Comment: I was actually talking about Apache s3a committer https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/committers.html, they should not have file type limitations.

Answer (score 0):

rename is mimicked on s3 with a copy then a delete and is O(data). Checkpoint more often to create smaller files

Comment: this happen under _SPARK_METADATA directory, which is WAL, not the raw data.